# Android AccountManager, Oauth, getAccessToken() does nothing except ask for password

Tags: android, oauth, google-api

After spending roughly two days on this, I'm getting a little rattled.  Although by now, having chosen OAuth2 over OpenID, I'm pretty well versed on the difference between Authenticate and Authorize.

I want my android app to provide several ways to authenticate users, one of them is google accounts, and later also facebook and twitter accounts.  I'm trying to use the AccountManager class to get an OAuth access token to (for now) just verify the user's email address.  The goal is that if the user already has a google account saved on the android device, they can authorize my app once, MAYBE even without typing a password, and never have to login again from their android.

I decided to use Google's own AccountManager as it promised to handle much of this natively in the Android framework, without even opening a browser window.  I am using the library / build target for google APIs version 7 (Android 2.1), the first level that supports AccountManager.

I have tried this two different ways, one using AccountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures() where you do not specify an Account object, and the other using getAuthToken() where you do specify such an object.

In each case, the call completes (as I expect it to) and the application displays an authorization dialog asking if I want to authorize the app.  So far, so good.  If I refuse, the program throws the exception that I expect.  If I accept, a "Google sign-in" dialog appears asking me for the password to the account.  Note that I already entered the password when I added the account to the device.  If I type the password in the dialog, there is an "Authorizing" wait screen and then the same dialog re-appears.  Oddly enough, the "Authorizing" wait screen seems to take a little bit longer if I type the CORRECT password.  So it appears that I cannot get to the code path where I successfully obtain the token.

As tempting as it is to vent about google not being clear about what AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE is or the fact that the userinfo.email URL is undocumented, I would really just like to learn what I am doing wrong here and move past this.

Here is my code, I will monitor this and of course be happy to answer any questions.  Right now I am going to work on getting a capture of the network traffic, to see if that provides any further insight into what is going wrong.

Here are images showing the auth screen (ok) and the password dialog (less ok)
http://imageshack.us/g/707/device20120609020618.png/

```
    public void loginToGoogle() {
    System.out.println("Starting");
    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> bundleFuture = 
        AccountManager.get(_activity).getAuthTokenByFeatures(
                "com.google", 
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", 
                null, 
                _activity, 
                null, 
                null, 
                new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                      public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                        Bundle bundle;
                        try {
                          bundle = future.getResult();
                          for (String s : bundle.keySet()) {
                              System.out.println("Found key: "+ s);
                          }

                          System.out.println(bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME));
                          System.out.println(bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
                          //Use Token


                        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                          Log.e("e", e.getMessage(), e);
                          System.out.println("User appears to have denied auth request");
                        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                          Log.e("e", e.getMessage(), e);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                          Log.e("e", e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                      }
                    }, 
                    null);
    System.out.println("Done with AccountManager call");
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Google Api Java Client?

Comment: I am using the library / build target for google APIs version 7 (Android 2.1), the first level that supports AccountManager.  This setting is mutually exclusive with just using Android 2.1 without google API's.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue most likely lies in the Auth Token Type you pass into the getAuthTokenByFeatures. Since you're using oauth2, you need to add it to beginning of your auth type:

```
String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
```

However, I'm not positive that the Auth Token Type you are trying to use is valid. I've only dealt with calendars and tasks myself. Hope this works out, if not, just let me know and I'll find you the right Auth type

Comment: I just plugged this in and it worked.  You are my hero.  I remember seeing the oauth2: notation elsewhere but it was not listed this way even when I went to 'Oauth2 Playground' (a nice tool) https://code.google.com/oauthplayground   The only issue is that this Auth type does not have a proper 'alias', that is, the user is literally asked if he wants to allow the app to "oauth2:https://...".  Do you happen to know if there is an alias for this?  i.e. if you plug in "Manage your tasks", it works for the tasks API

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. I believe I read somewhere that they're working on updating this.

Comment: You guys are my heroes, I've been trying to figure this out for the longest time and Google does NOT make it easy. I do have a follow up question though. Is there a way to set a more user-friendly message in the Access Request window so instead of it asking for permission to access oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email or in my case oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar you can set it to display something like "Your calendars"?